# Remove identical duplicate rows in data in R

Tags: r

I have a data as below:

```
col.1   col.2   col.3  col.4  
Alex    Cleaner  100   USA  
Ruby    Cleaner  300   UK  
Alex    Manager  500   USA  
Ruby    Chef     300   USA  
Alex    Cleaner  100   USA
```

And need to delete row number 1 or 5 as both are identically same. Can someone help with the easiest way in R?

Comment: check out `?duplicated()`

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
df[!duplicated(df), ]
```

Comment: A little more explanation will make this answer more useful for the OP and for future users...